# Using pass credential helper on Ubuntu 18.04.3 for Docker Login

Tags: linux, docker, passwords, credentials

I have followed several apparently easy instructions on the following pages to try to get docker login  to work with 'pass' cred helper, but I still always get the password prompt for some reason.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53912/i-try-to-add-passwords-to-the-pass-password-manager-but-my-attempts-fail-with

https://github.com/docker/docker-credential-helpers/issues/102

Can anyone spot what I am failing to discern from these documents?   Here is from what I understand is the relevant information from my server:

OS Version:

```
root@brdvsslx:~/.docker# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Pass configuration:

```
root@brdvsslx:~/.docker# pass
Password Store
├── docker-credential-helpers
│   ├── docker-pass-initialized-check
│   ├── stevesun
│   └── stsimsun
└── LXI
    └── stevesun
```

Docker Config file:

```
root@brdvsslx:~/.docker# cat config.json
{
        "credHelpers": {
                "harbor.<xxx>.com": "pass"
        },
        "credsStore": "pass",
        "auths": {},
        "HttpHeaders": {
                "User-Agent": "Docker-Client/18.09.7 (linux)"
        }
}
```

Login attempt:

```
root@brdvsslx:~/.docker# docker login harbor.<xxx>.com
Username: stevesun
Password:
Error: Password Required
root@brdvsslx:~/.docker#
```

Note: I have cleansed various personalized info from above.

From what I have read, given the above information it should be sufficient to work.   I know docker is reading the config.json file because it reports if I accidentally put a syntax error in there.

Edit: Additional Info:

I found a part of the initialization that I missed, but there is still an issue:

```
pass insert docker-credential-helpers/docker-pass-initialized-check and set the next password "pass is initialized" (without quotes).
```

Once I did that, a docker login would retain the passwords in pass until the server was restarted, and then it became uninitialized again.

However, once initialized again, it did retain (remember) my previously entered docker credentials.

I don't think that's correct behavior is it?